# Set the date in Beaglebone Black using ntp Debian 8.9

Tags: date, debian, beagleboneblack, ntp

I've been trying to set up the correct date in my Beaglebone Black but the solutions I've tried are not permanent, everytime I poweroff the Beagle and power on later, the date is wrong again.
So this is what initially looks like:

```
root@beaglebone:~# date
Sat May 21 17:48:28 CDT 2016
```

Then I installed ntp and ntpdate

```
root@beaglebone:~# apt-get install ntp ntpdate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ntp is already the newest version.
ntpdate is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

After that I edit the ntp.conf file like this

```
# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
...
# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust
restrict 192.168.0.11 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
```

The next step was

```
root@beaglebone:~# rm /etc/localtime
root@beaglebone:~# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Mexico_City /etc/localtime
```

After that I was supposed to enable the ntp service with

```
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable ntpdate.service
Failed to enable unit: No such file or directory

or

root@beaglebone:~# service ntpdate start
Failed to start ntpdate.service: Unit ntpdate.service not found.
```

I couldn't continue with thas because I don't have the ntp.service file so then I tried this

```
root@beaglebone:~# timedatectl set-ntp true
root@beaglebone:~# timedatectl status
      Local time: Sat 2016-05-21 18:16:10 CDT
  Universal time: Sat 2016-05-21 23:16:10 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2016-05-21 23:16:11
       Time zone: America/Mexico_City (CDT, -0500)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no

root@beaglebone:~# nano /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
[Time]
NTP=0.north-america.pool.ntp.org 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
FallbackNTP=0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

Finally I reboot and seems to work

```
root@beaglebone:~# timedatectl status
      Local time: Sun 2017-09-10 23:32:28 CDT
  Universal time: Mon 2017-09-11 04:32:28 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2017-09-11 04:32:28
       Time zone: America/Mexico_City (CDT, -0500)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

But then again, after poweroff the time sets itself back to May 21st, 2016. I even tried set and sync the clock manually with hwclock --set --date "date" --localtime and systohc but after poweroff the result is the same.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I also change 'UTC' to 'LOCAL' in /etc/adjtime and time goes back to May 2016.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

This should work. A prompt appears and you can configure it with a graphical interface. It is as easy as America and enter. And then, you can pick your time zone, too.

Seth

Comment: Tried that and didn't work, It sets the time zone so as the procedure I posted in the questions but still resets at boot.